# Diferencia entre header y include en lenguaje C

Tags: c

Será que un header es lo mismo que un include? O son diferentes?
Es que un amigo me dijo que eran distinto pero nunca me trató de decir la diferencia.

Yo lo que entiendo es que el include es la directiva quien incluye el archivo externo y el header básicamente es como si fuera la librería donde está el código a incluir. No sé si lo que dije está bien o que.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Antes de que el compilador tenga oportunidad de ver el código, el preprocesador lo lee y lo transforma potencialmente en otra cosa, siguiendo las directivas de preprocesador que estén incluidas en el fuente.

Un `#include` es una de esas directivas para el preprocesador, que le indica que en ese punto incluya el contenido de otro fichero. Lo que recibe el compilador es como si tú mismo hubieras abierto el fichero indicado por el `#include` y lo hubieras copiado y pegado literalmente en el programa principal.

Por tanto el contenido de un fichero `.h` ha de ser código C válido. En realidad puede ser cualquier código (podría incluir por ejemplo el código fuente que implemente algunas funciones), pero no suele ser el caso. Lo habitual es que contenga tan solo *declaraciones* (tipos de datos o prototipos de funciones), mientras que la implementación en sí no está en el `.h`, sino en otros `.c` que se compilarán separadamente y se añadirán al principal, o se almacenarán en bibliotecas.

El compilador, gracias a esos prototipos que se han traído del `.h`, puede chequear que cuando invocas una función le estás pasando los parámetros correctos y de los tipos apropiados. No obstante el compilador no necesita para eso tener el código de las funciones, le basta con sus prototipos.

Para montar el ejecutable final, una vez el compilador ha terminado, viene el montador de enlaces (*linker*), el cual recopila el código máquina generado por el compilador más el de otros ficheros compilados, más el de las bibliotecas externas necesarias, y con todo ello resuelve las llamadas a las funciones que se hayan usado. Si alguna de las funciones declaradas en el `.h` (e invocadas luego desde el programa) no aparece a la hora de montar, habrá un error en tiempo de enlazado.

A los archivos `.h` se les llama "archivos de cabecera", o *headers*. Mucha gente los llama también librerías. Esto es erróneo, y no por cuestiones pedantes como que librería no es la traducción correcta de *library* (que debería ser biblioteca), sino porque un `.h` contiene *código fuente* (y es usado por el compilador), mientras que una bibioteca (o librería si quieres) contiene *código máquina* y es usado por el montador de enlaces.

### Actualización

Esta larga actualización es para responder algunas dudas adicionales planteadas por el usuario en los comentarios sobre los errores en tiempo de enlazado.

El siguiente ejemplo ayuda a ilustrar la diferencia entre las dos fases de la creación de un ejecutable:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
    double area;
    double radio;

    printf("Area del circulo? ");
    scanf("%lf", &area);
    radio = sqrt(area/M_PI);
    printf("El circulo de area %g tiene un radio %g\n", area, radio);

    return 0;
}
```

Al incluir `math.h`, el preprocesador incluye en ese punto todo el contenido del fichero `math.h`. Entre otras cosas dentro de ese fichero se define la constante `M_PI` con el valor `3.1415926etc...` y se proporciona el prototipo de la función `sqrt()`. En realidad es algo más complejo porque el prototipo de esa función se define a través de una macro, pero para nuestros efectos podemos imaginar que el fichero contiene una línea así:

```
double sqrt(double);
```

Gracias a esa declaración el compilador puede verificar, cuando en nuestro programa invocamos `sqrt()`, que el tipo que le pasamos como parámetro es correcto, y que lo que devuelve la función puede ser asignado a la variable `radio`, o si el tipo de `radio` fuese `float`, qué conversiones automáticas deberían realizarse.

Sin embargo, si intentas compilar este ejemplo, obtendrás un error (al menos con el `gcc` en Linux):

```
$ gcc area.c
/tmp/cc7yPPMr.o: En la función `main':
area.c:(.text+0x4e): referencia a `sqrt' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Este es un error en tiempo de enlazado (el `ld` a que se refiere el error es el nombre del *linker*).

No se produce si a `gcc` le pides que "solo compile" (es decir, que haga la primera fase pero no la segunda):

```
$ gcc -c area.c
$ ls
area.c  area.o
```

En este caso no hay errores, y el resultado de la compilación es `area.o`. Pero este no es un ejecutable completo. Sólo tiene el código máquina de la función `main`, pero no el de otras funciones que son invocadas desde `main`, como `scanf()`, `printf()` o `sqrt()`.

Por ello hace falta la segunda fase, la de enlazado, que podemos hacer manualmente, pero de nuevo obtenemos error:

```
$ gcc -o area area.o
area.o: En la función `main':
area.c:(.text+0x4e): referencia a `sqrt' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Observa que, ya que el *linker* toma como entrada `area.o` en vez de `area.c`, ya no está viendo el código fuente, sino el código máquina que generó el compilador. En ese código máquina la misión del *linker* es "rellenar los huecos". El compilador dejó marcas como "aquí va una llamada a una función `printf`, aquí va otra a una función `sqrt`. El *linker* debe buscar el código máquina de esas funciones, añadirlas al ejecutable y rellenar en esos huecos las direcciones necesarias para el `CALL`.

¿De dónde saca el *linker* el código máquina de esas otras funciones? Pues básicamente de tres sitios:

- De otros ficheros `.o` que hayas especificado en el comando al invocar al *linker* (no hemos puesto ninguno en este caso)
- De bibliotecas (librerías) adicionales que hayas especificado en el comando al invocar al linker, mediante la opción `-l` (no hemos puesto ninguna en este caso)
- De la biblioteca estándar C, que es una biblioteca que el *linker* siempre consulta por defecto (por tanto en el ejemplo anterior, la única que estaríamos usando).

Resulta que la biblioteca estándar C tiene el código máquina de las funciones `printf` y `scanf`, por lo que éstas no presentan problemas. Pero no tiene el código de `sqrt`, porque esa está en la librería matemática, la cual no es buscada por defecto. Por eso el *linker* no la encuentra y da error.

Fíjate que el error del *linker* se limita a mostrar el nombre de la función que no encuentra y el de la función desde la cual fue llamada, pero no te puede decir desde qué línea concreta de `area.c` se hizo esa llamada, porque el *linker* no lee el fuente (de hecho podrías haberlo borrado ya tras la primera fase de compilación).

Para evitar este error hay que decirle al *linker* en este caso que busque también en la librería matemática, para lo que debe usarse la opción `-lm`. Entonces:

```
$ gcc -o area area.o -lm
$ ls
area   area.c   area.o
```

Ahora sí, el archivo `area` es el ejecutable final.

También podríamos haber ejecutado las dos fases con un solo comando, en vez de hacerlo separadamente:

```
$ gcc -o area area.c -lm
```

Fíjate que la única diferencia es que he puesto `area.c` (por lo que `gcc` primero lo compilará y luego lo enlazará) en vez de `area.o` (en cuyo caso la fase de compilación se saltaba por estar ya hecha).

**Aún hay más**

Un último detalle, un tanto sorprendente. Decíamos que el compilador sólo necesita el prototipo de la función, pero no su código. De hecho ¡no necesita ni el prototipo!

Puedes hacer el siguiente experimento. En `area.c` cambia la llamada a `sqrt()` por otra a `raiz_cuadrada()`, función que ni ha sido declarada ni existe, e intenta "compilar solo", sin enlazar:

```
$ gcc -c area.c
area.c: In function ‘main’:
area.c:11:13: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘raiz_cuadrada’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     radio = raiz_cuadrada(area/M_PI);
```

Como ves obtenemos un *warning*, pero no un error. El compilador generará un `.o`, dejando un hueco para el *linker* que dice "y aquí debe venir la llamada a la función `raiz_cuadrada`". Naturalmente el *linker* no la encontrará y producirá un error en tiempo de enlazado como antes.

Pero ¿cómo es posible que el compilador no haya dado un error cuando estamos llamando a una función que no existe? Pues porque cuando el compilador encuentra una llamada a una función no declarada, *se inventa él mismo la declaración*. Es lo que llama una declaración implícita, y es de lo que nos está advirtiendo el *warning*. La declaración que el compilador inventa se basa en la llamada que hemos hecho. Como ve que le pasamos un parámetro de tipo `double`, asume que la declaración sería `raiz_cuadrada(double)`. Sin embargo para el valor retornado siempre asume `int`, lo que sería erróneo en este caso. Por eso es importante incluir los `.h` adecuados, para evitar que el compilador "invente" declaraciones incorrectas.

Comment: Hola abulafia. Gracias por tu respuesta. No sabía lo de "librerías", siempre pensé que eran "includes" , pero ahora investigando me doy cuenta que son simples archivos objetos (binarios) empleados por el enlazador (asi como dijiste). Pero tengo una duda. A que te refieres un error en tiempo de enlazado?

Comment: @MrDave1999 La creación de un ejecutable tiene lugar en dos fases. La primera es la compilación, que toma un fuente y lo convierte en un objeto binario que es el código máquina. Ese binario contiene el código de las funciones implementadas en ese fuente, pero no el de otras funciones a las que llama y de las que sólo se tenía el prototipo. La segunda fase es el enlazado, que junta varios objetos binarios y librerías en un solo ejecutable. Cuando el compilador encuentra una llamada a una función de la que no tiene el código, no puede completar la instrucción máquina CALL, por lo que...

Comment: ... deja un "hueco" en el objeto binario, con marcas indicando a que función habría que llamar. Cuando el montador de enlaces junta todo en un solo ejecutable, completa esos huecos. Si el linker no encuentra alguna funcion en ninguno de los objetos ni librerias que está enlazando, no puede completarse el ejecutable, y da un error. Este error no puede señalar en qué línea del fuente se produjo el,problema, pues el linker ya no ve fuentes, solo binarios.

Comment: El comando `gcc` lanza por defecto ambas fases en secuencia (y suele borrar los objetos binarios intermedios) a menos que uses la opción `-c`, en cuyo caso hace solo la compilación, sin enlazado, y deja como resultado un archivo de extensión `.o`.

Comment: pero esto no dependería del compilador? Pues por ejemplo, el compiler de Visual Studio te da un error de sintaxis si no encuentra la implementación de la función y esto hace que el enlazador nunca se ejecute y haga su función.                   Será que el pre-procesador y el enlazador son .exe? o simple plugins ejecutados por el mismo compilador? Siempre tuve esa duda.

Comment: Entonces supongamos que el compilador no hace nada si no encuentra la función y el enlazador se da cuenta que falta el código de esa función. ¿Qué consecuencias traería? Será que el compilador se dejaría de funcionar?

Comment: @MrDave1999 Aclararte estas dudas requiere un ejemplo y extensas explicaciones. Lo he añadido a mi respuesta. Espero te guste!