# ¿Como poner cadenas en un arreglo bidimensional en C?

Tags: array, c, funciones, condiciones, array-bidimensional

soy nuevo en la programación, estoy haciendo un programa que obtenga las calificaciones N alumnos, sus nombres y determinar su condición, todo en funciones diferentes, la cosa es que estoy teniendo problemas para poner la condición de los alumnos ya que el ejercicio pide que se pase a la función un arreglo de condiciones vacio.

El arreglo *condicion* lo cree a partir del numero de alumnos y como la palabras *Satisfactorio* y *Sobresaliente* son las mas largas y ambas contienen 13 caracteres (14 mas el carácter nulo según entiendo) puse 15 en el otro tamaño para redondear.

Me da error dentro de los condicionales if en donde estoy tratando de asignarle las palabras al arreglo y el error que me lanza el compilador (Codeblocks) es el sigiuente:

> error assignment to expression with array type

Espero me puedan orientar, gracias.

```html
void calificar(int calis[ALUMNOS], char condicion[ALUMNOS][15])
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < ALUMNOS; i++)
    {
        if (calis[i] < 6)
        {
            condicion[i] = "Reprobado";
        }
        if (calis[i] > 6 && calis[i] <= 8)
        {
            condicion[i] =  "Satisfactorio";
        }
        if (calis[i] >= 9)
        {
            condicion[i] = "Sobresaliente";
        }
    }

    for(j = 0; j < ALUMNOS; j++)
    {
        printf("\nLa condicion de alumno %d es: %s", j+1, condicion[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

La forma en la que asignas la cadena no es correcta, usa `strcpy` de la libreria `string.h` y asigna la cadena de esta forma:

```
strcpy(condicion[i], "Reprobado");
```

Comment: `string.h` no es una *librería* sino un *archivo de encabezado*.

Comment: Creo que es correcto también llamarlas librerías, no se si me estoy perdiendo en algo, pero yo aprendí a llamarlas "librerías" más que como "archivos de encabezado".

Comment: Tuve esa misma duda hace mucho tiempo. Mira este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/211664/diferencia-entre-header-y-include-en-lenguaje-c).

Comment: Definitivamente tiene sentido, puede ser más correcto llamarlos "archivos de encabezado" para no confundirlas con las bibliotecas estáticas o también dll's que usamos en muchos proyectos, aunque tampoco estoy seguro si sea totamente incorrecto llamar a los archivos de encabezado también librerías, [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/48305/154404) parece que no las diferencian mucho.

Comment: En la [wiki](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblioteca_(inform%C3%A1tica)) lo explica claramente, una **biblioteca** contiene código binario.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, en C no es posible asignar una cadena literal a un array o matriz (de tipo `char`) después de su declaración.

**Por ejemplo:**

```c
char name[24];
name = "Ivan";//error

char names[100][24];
names[0] = "Ivan";//error
```

El ejemplo de arriba dará un error de compilación, debido a que, es ilegal asignar una cadena después de su declaración.

Por lo tanto, la solución más simple es la de @4lrdyD, sin embargo, no es recomendable usar la función `strcpy` para copiar cadenas constantes (es decir, siempre es la misma durante la ejecución del programa) en un búfer, debido a que, harás el programa lento y consumirá memoria.

**¿Por qué es ineficiente?**

Porque en cada iteración estarías copiando la misma cadena (por eso es constante) en `X` fila de la matriz `condicion`.

Por ejemplo, si la condición fuera para `100` alumnos. La matriz `condicion` estaría consumiendo `1500` bytes.

Y esto lo compruebas de esta manera:

```c
char condicion[100][15];
printf("%d\n", sizeof condicion);
```

Entonces sería un desperdicio de memoria estar copiando la misma cadena en cada fila de la matriz `condicion`, por esa razón es ineficiente.

Para optimizar este código podríamos usar un arreglo de punteros a `char`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ALUMNOS 100

void calificar(int[], char*[]);

//Code example:
int main (void)
{
    int calis[ALUMNOS] = {9};
    char* condicion[ALUMNOS];
    calificar(calis, condicion);
    return 0;
}

void calificar(int calis[], char* condicion[])
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < ALUMNOS; i++)
    {
        if (calis[i] < 6)
            condicion[i] = "Reprobado";
        if (calis[i] > 6 && calis[i] <= 8)
            condicion[i] =  "Satisfactorio";
        if (calis[i] >= 9)
            condicion[i] = "Sobresaliente";
    }
    for(j = 0; j < ALUMNOS; j++)
        printf("\nLa condicion de alumno %d es: %s", j+1, condicion[j]);
}
```

**¿Por qué es más eficiente?**

Porque no estamos copiando en cada iteración la misma cadena. La cadenas literales: `Reprobado`, `Satisfactorio` y `Sobresaliente` están alojados en un bloque de memoria, por ende, cada puntero del arreglo de punteros apuntarán a cualquiera de esos **tres** bloques de memoria. Por lo tanto, estaríamos ahorrando memoria y tiempo.

**Recalco** esta es una optimización que hace el compilador. Por lo tanto, se debe asegurar que las optimizaciones que haga el compilador estén activadas.

Por ejemplo, el compilador `cl.exe` (de Visual Studio) no hará esta optimización hasta que le pases el comando `/Ox` (ver este [hilo](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/build/reference/ox-full-optimization?view=vs-2019)).